# How to design custom keypad in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I have designed a custom keypad as shown below  but its keys are blurred how to make it look nice  [image]

below is the java code in which keyboard view in inflated

```
@Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
       // keyboard_sym = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.symbol);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);

        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        Log.e(TAG,"Started");
        return kv;
    }
```

---

Below is xml file code

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="8dp"
    android:verticalGap="5dp"

    android:keyHeight="40dp"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    >
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"  />
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
        <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
        <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
        <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
        <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
        <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
        <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
        <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
        <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
        <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="s"/>
        <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="d"/>
        <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="f"/>
        <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="g"/>
        <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="h"/>
        <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="j"/>
        <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="k"/>
        <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="l" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>

    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"  android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyIcon="@drawable/arrow"/>
        <Key android:codes="122" android:keyLabel="z"/>
        <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x"/>
        <Key android:codes="99" android:keyLabel="c"/>
        <Key android:codes="118" android:keyLabel="v"/>
        <Key android:codes="98" android:keyLabel="b"/>
        <Key android:codes="110" android:keyLabel="n"/>
        <Key android:codes="109" android:keyLabel="m"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5"  android:keyIcon="@drawable/backspace" android:keyWidth="15%p" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>

    </Row>
    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key  android:codes="1000" android:keyLabel="Sys" android:keyWidth="20%p"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:keyWidth="40%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="." android:keyWidth="10%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="-4"  android:keyIcon="@drawable/downleft" android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

How to change the color of key so it  not look blurred ?

Answer (score 0):

The keys of a keyboard are grouped as rows. It's good practice to limit the number of keys on a row to a maximum of ten, with each key having a width equal to 10% of the keyboard. The height of the keys  can be adjusted, but values less than 48dp are not recommended. Change KeyHeight and check once.